# Append columns to python cursor before writing to CSV?

Tags: python, sql, csv, pyodbc

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import pyodbc

out_file = "file.csv"

conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={driver};SERVER=servername;UID=user;PWD=pass;DATABASE=data")

cursor = conn.execute("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table")

with open(out_file, 'w') as f:
  print cursor
  csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL).writerows(cursor)
```

That is my code as of now, and that works as expected. My question is, how would I add a few null-valued columns to the row before inserting it into the CSV? I need to do this because I'll be combining it with another query that is going to have a few extra data columns and I'd like the data to line up with null-filled columns.

Comment: Unrelated tip: you should move the creation of the csv writer outside the loop: `writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)`, that way a new writer object is not created for each write.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, `writerows` will write all the available data so there's no loop and only one writer object is created.

Comment: @MarkRansom:  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for row in cursor:
    writer.writerow(list(row) + ['', '', '', ''])
```

Comment: The OP should move the creation of the csv writer outside the loop: `writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)`, that way a new writer object is not created for each write.

Comment: I've tried this already, I get `AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'extend'`

Comment: @user485418, sorry I didn't know what type `cursor` returned. I assumed it was a list because `writerows` accepted it. I've made another edit.

Comment: Well, no error this time, but nothing was appended unfortunately. As an aside, assuming we get something working, will there be a way for me to append a few blank columns in the middle of a `row`?

Comment: @user485418, you can use slice notation to add something to the middle of a row once it's been converted to a `list`, e.g. `row[4:4] = ['', '']` should add the two blanks before column 4 (0-based).

Comment: I've made it work with a slight modification (not sure why this works, but yours doesn't):
`row = list(row) + [True]
writer.writerow(row)`